# Conflict jQuery and Joomla after migrate of Joomla 2.5 to 3.3

Tags: jquery, conflict, joomla3.0

I migrate of Joomla 2.5 to 3.3 and this jQuery don't work (worked perfectly in Joomla 2.5)

```
        <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery().timelinr({
            arrowKeys: 'true'
        })
    });
</script>
```

This is the source site [jQuery Timelinr](http://www.csslab.cl/2011/08/18/jquery-timelinr)

What can i do?

Comment: What version of jQuery is being used now, and what version was being used beforehand? That looks like a big version leap, and the bundled version of jQuery has probably been updated.

Comment: Joomla uses Mootools by default, I think. Not jQuery

Comment: I am testing locally independent and works with jQuery 1.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.I install jQuery Easy, and the Option "Migrate" I choose "Joomla! framework". 
2.Additionally I had to change $ per jquery in the script that had conflict.